# change color of a word in div value using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `<div id="one">this is a sentence</div>`

I have a textbox for userinput, if the user types a word which matches any word in div, eg: if user types "this", which is also there in div value, the background color of "this" should be changed, using Javascript

Thanks 
Sunny.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  `onkeypress` is what you need for the input box, followed by a knowledge of working with ranges in a cross browser manner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Connect the textbox to a onkeypress event
2. In the event function, do an filter for each word that is typed, and match it to words in the div.
3. For each matched word, replace the `word` in the div with `<span style="background-color:yellow;">word</span>` by modifying the content of `one.innerHTML`.

Note, before you modify the div, you should store the original content in a global variable that is used as base for the matching, otherwise, the matching will be cluttered with the `<span...>` tags.

Comment: its working but after it changes the color, the page refreshes and the changes are undone.

Comment: Hi,
what if i want to change the color of next word to the matching word.
for eg: refering above code(top), "this" is searched string, so i want to color "is". how can i do it in javascript?

Comment: Advanced searching/matching can be done by using regular expressions, but I am not an expert there, so others might want to answer this.